# Google Functions v2 and NestJs

Tags: google-cloud-functions, nestjs

I'm looking into spinning up an api with nest using google cloud functions v2, looks like some people is doing it using nx: https://itnext.io/a-perfect-match-nestjs-cloud-functions-2nd-gen-nx-workspace-f13fb044e9a4, can this be done using nx?

I'm looking into a more vanilla example just using functions-framework and nest. Can somebody point me to any repo or example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nx is just tooling. It should be the same as you implement without NX. Can you try it in a normal Nestjs project?

```
// main.ts
const server = express()
import { http } from '@google-cloud/functions-framework'

export const createNestServer = async (expressInstance) => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(expressInstance))
const globalPrefix = 'api'
  app.setGlobalPrefix(globalPrefix)
  app.enableCors()
  return app.init()
}

createNestServer(server)
  .then((v) => {
    if (environment.production) {
      Logger.log(' Starting production server...')
    } else {
      Logger.log(` Starting development server on http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 3333}`)
      v.listen(process.env.PORT || 3333)
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => Logger.error('Nest broken', err))

http('apiNEST', server)
```

Comment: Ok! Will give it a go, btw is the gcloud invocation command still in beta?

Comment: It's GA now, so you don't have to use beta. Example 

```
gcloud functions deploy nodejs-http-function \
  --gen2 \
  --runtime nodejs16 \
  --entry-point helloWorld \
  --source . \
  --region $REGION \
  --trigger-http \
  --timeout 600s
```